# I want to access some variables from previous build of the same job in jenkins pipeline , i.e. share some common variables between builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a situation where I need to share some variables between build of the same job . I want to have a condition where based on those variables I decide to run further stages or not . This is to give more priority to some builds and less to others.

Comment: What do you mean by "some variables"? Are they build parameters or just groovy variable defined in your Jenkinsfile? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have tried with build variables it doesn't work ,I want to do it with variables like def priority =0